# Multi-part identifier in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    customer.custm_no, customer.name,customer.name2,
    orderhdr.otype,orderhdr.saleorder,
    orderdtl.sitno,orderdtl.qty,
    delvdtl.qty,delvdtl.issueqty
    material.name,develhdr.nodelv
FROM
    customer
    left join orderhdr on customer.custm_no = orderhdr.custm_no 
    left join orderdtl on orderhdr.otype = orderdtl.otype   
      and        orderhdr.SALEORDER = orderdtl.SALEORDER
    left join delvdtl on orderdtl.SALEORDER = delvdtl.SALEORDER   
    AND  orderdtl.sitno = delvdtl.sitno
    left join  develhdr on delvdtl.nodelv = develhdr.nodelv 
    left join MATMSTA on   material.MATNO = MATMSTA.MATNO   
    left join material on  MATMSTA.MATNO = material.MATNO 
    and MATMSTA.MATNO = material.MATNO
    left join  plantcocode on plant.plant = plantcocode.plant
   left join plant on orderdtl.plant = plantcocode.plant
   left join cocode  on plantcocode.cocode = cocode.cocode 
WHERE
    1 = 1   
order by
 orderdtl.saleorder, orderdtl.sitno
```

But this shows me:

> The multi-part identifier "material .MATNO" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "plant.plant" could not be bound.

after edit

```
    SELECT customer.custm_no, customer.name,customer.name2,orderhdr.otype,orderhdr.saleorder,orderdtl.sitno,orderdtl.qty,delvdtl.qty,delvdtl.issueqtymaterial.name,develhdr.nodelv
FROM customer
  left join orderhdr on customer.custm_no = orderhdr.custm_no 
  left join orderdtl on orderhdr.otype = orderdtl.otype   
  and        orderhdr.SALEORDER = orderdtl.SALEORDER
 left join delvdtl on orderdtl.SALEORDER = delvdtl.SALEORDER   
   AND  orderdtl.sitno = delvdtl.sitno
        left join  develhdr on delvdtl.nodelv = develhdr.nodelv 
        left join material on delvdtl.MATNO = material.MATNO 
      left join plant on orderdtl.plant = plant.plant
      left join  plantcocode on plant.plant = plantcocode.plant
    left join cocode  on plantcocode.cocode = cocode.cocode
     WHERE
        1 = 1   
    order by
     orderdtl.saleorder, orderdtl.sitno
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your query:
1) There is no `customer` table/alias in your query. Is it `CUSTMST` which you should be giving an alias name of `customer`? 
2) `MATMSTA` needs to be joined to some table above it in the `FROM` clause. 
3) You have mentioned the same `join` condition twice while joining `MATMSTA` and `material` table. It should only be given once.

Correct these issues and it should be fine.

Comment: 1st i correct now check plz.. and 2nd and 3rd point please specify

Comment: `MATMSTA` table should be joined to one of the tables above them in the join list. This line `left join material on  MATMSTA.MATNO = material.MATNO 
    and MATMSTA.MATNO = material.MATNO` should be `left join material on  MATMSTA.MATNO = material.MATNO`. But you need to also mention which records should come out from `MATMSTA` table. Currently there is no such condition.

Comment: pleae check after edit part. when i execute this shows me The multi-part identifier "plant.plant" could not be bound.

Comment: the `left join` on `plant` should come before the `left join` on `plantcocode`. You should also remove `and plant.plant = plantcocode.plant` in the `left join plant` line as this is already been taken care in the `left join plantcocode` join.

Comment: now this shows The multi-part identifier "plantcocode.plant" could not be bound. :(

Comment: ok i change this line  left join plant on orderdtl.plant = plantcocode.plant to left join plant on orderdtl.plant = plant .plant is this right?

Comment: Look at the after Edit query.

Comment: `left join plant on orderdtl.plant = plant.plant left join  plantcocode on plant.plant = plantcocode.plant` this is what you need to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107671/discussion-between-amit-and-bakhtawar).